# Casting to a generic interface with a dynamic type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, type-inference

I have two generic interfaces like these:

```
public interface IFoo<T> { }
public interface IBar<TFoo, T> where TFoo : Foo<T> { 
    T Qux(TFoo foo);
}
```

`IFoo<T>` has a bunch of implementations, each with a matching implementation of `IBar<S,T>`, registered in my IoC container (which happens to be Castle.Windsor).

Now, I want to create a method which, based on an argument of some type that implements `IFoo<T>`, returns a corresponding `IBar<IFoo<T>,T>` from Windsor. A naïve implementation looks like this:

```
public IBar<TFoo,T> GetBarFor(IFoo<T> foo) where TFoo : IFoo<T>
{
    return container.Resolve<IBar<TFoo,T>>();
}
```

However, in the calling code, I don't have a concretely typed `Foo<T>` - just an `IFoo<T>`:

```
public T DoStuffWithStuff<T>(IFoo<T> foo)
{
    var bar = GetBarFor(foo);
    return bar.Qux(foo);
}
```

and in this call, the compiler is unable to deduce the type parameters (specifically, I guess, `TFoo`), so I need to take another approach.

I have tried to resolve the type with the non-generic version of `Resolve()`, but then I can't get the return type right:

```
public AbstractBar<T> GetBarFor(IFoo<T> foo) where TFoo : IFoo<T>
{
    var barType = typeof(IBar<,>).MakeGenericType(foo.GetType(),typeof(T));
    var bar = container.Resolve(barType); // bar is now a System.Object

    var wrapperType = typeof(BarWrapper<,>).MakeGenericType(foo.GetType(), typeof(T));
    var wrapper = Activator.CreateInstance(wrapperType, bar);

    return (AbstractBar<T>)wrapper;
}
```

with

```
public abstract class AbstractBar<T> { public abstract T Qux(IFoo<T> foo); }

public class BarWrapper<TFoo, T> : AbstractBar<T> where TFoo : IFoo<T>
{
    private IBar<TFoo,T> _inner;
    public BarWrapper(IBar<TFoo,T> inner) { _inner = inner; }

    public T Qux(IFoo<T> foo) { return _inner.Qux((TFoo)foo); }
}
```

but I keep getting exceptions on the `Activator.CreateInstance` call saying that the constructor for `BarWrapper` is not found (yes, everything is `public`).

Is there a good way to get the call in `DoStuffWithStuff` above working for exactly that signature (i.e. I can't defer any more specific generics from the calling code)?

---

<sup>Footnote: I have seen the latter pattern work, in [Jimmie Bogard's MediatR implementation of the mediator pattern](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR), and in fact what I'm trying to accomplish here is a very similar implementation, that doesn't rely on the Common Service Locator, but rather goes straight to our IoC container. In context, `IFoo<T>` is really `IRequest<out TResponse>`, `IBar<TFoo, T>` is really `IRequestHandler<in TRequest, out TResponse>`, etc.</sup>

<sup>Looking at his code, and trying to recreate it but with a call to the Windsor container instead of the service locator, I can't figure out why his code works, and mine does not.</sup>

Comment: Side note: instead of "yes, everything is public" it may be better to show correct code like `public BarWrapper(...`

Comment: class BarWrapper { BarWrapper(); ... } are you sure that constructor a public?

Comment: Have you tried to get non-reflection version of `GetBarFor` to work first? (specify type instead `foo.GetType()` and get it to compile/run)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov and Igor: I was trying to save myself some typing, but I realize why that is confusing. I've updated the code samples to reflect the actual code.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yes, I tried that, and got it working, but it unfortunately requires me to provide type parameters all the way up to the call to `DoStuffWithStuff`, which I cannot have (it would defeat the purpose of injecting an IoC container into my mediator...). I haven't found a way to get this working at all, that doesn't either a) require type parameters in the outermost call, or b) use reflection.

Comment: I think your problem might be that the `IBar` interface and `BarWrapper` are mixing dependencies with `Foo<T>` and `IFoo<T>`. I have created 2 fiddles depending [only on `Foo<T>`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NUskWe) and [only on `IFoo<T>`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0QZLHK) that might help

Answer (score 0):

Untested but you need use reflection to late bind the type to the method info of the generic you want to execute.

```
      var wrapperType = typeof(BarWrapper<,>).MakeGenericType(foo.GetType(), typeof(T));

      MethodInfo TempMethodInfo = typeof(MYClass).GetMethod("DoStuffWithStuff")         

      MethodInfo GenericParam = TempMethodinfo.MakeGenericMethod(T);

      var Formatter = Delegate.CreateDelegate(wrapperType , GenericParam);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use good old `dynamic` keyword.

Essentially it allows the runtime to figure out the correct types.

```
IBar<TFoo,T> GetBarFor<TFoo, T>(TFoo dummy, IFoo<T> secondDummy) 
    where TFoo : IFoo<T>
{
    return container.Resolve<IBar<TFoo, T>>();
}
```

and the usage of `GetBarFor`:

```
GetBarFor((dynamic)foo, (dynamic)foo);
```